# Mocking class in Sinon.js and instanceof

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, instanceof, sinon

I want to mock some object of some Class, but catch this err:

```
function MyClass(){}

var myInstance = new MyClass();
var mock = sinon.mock(myInstance);

console.log(mock instanceof MyClass); // false
```

How can I pass this mock to the unit under the test, if unit checks exactly the same instanceof in a constructor?

I know, that stub solving this problem, but I need exactly Mock.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, Sinon mocks wrap their associated objects, rather than directly adopting their prototype chain, which means `instanceof` is never going to work as you want.

If you have the ability to change the unit under test, consider checking for the existence of important properties on the incoming object, rather than its prototype chain. For example, if your unit uses `MyClass`'s `foo` method, then have the unit check `typeof o.foo === 'function'` instead of `o instanceof MyClass`.

Comment: Of course, this is a solution - to check instance in style of ducktype, but it is a little bit hacky vs native language feature as `instanseof`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is wrong.

Instead of passing `mock` to unit under test, I need still pass the `myInstance` object, and then verify the `mock`:

```
new SUT(myInstance);
mock.verify();
```